# Image Texturing

Tags: texturing, image

I am trying to recreate my floor in my house from a picture I took and using an image texture.

I am having a sort white-washed texture effect happening. Does anyone know what's going on? The comparison of the two shows my floor image on top and the Node setup.

[image]

[image: Node Setup]

Answer (score 2):

The white spot in your render is just a reflection of your *Point light*.
To make it also visible in the *Viewport*, you have to enable your Scene Lights.

[image]

*Additional note.*
You seem a bit confused about using the *Bump node*.

If you're using it with a color image, add a color ramp to make it BW and to control the contrast.
There's no need for a Displacement node.

[image]

Comment: This was very insightful. Thank you!